# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json

Estoy tratando de mapear un JSON a un objeto en java, el JSON es algo asi:

```
{
    "usage": {
        "text_characters": 22,
        "features": 1,
        "text_units": 1
    },
    "entities": [{
        "count": 1,
        "text": "pisos",
        "disambiguation": {
            "subtype": ["NONE"]
        },
        "type": "Producto"
    }, {
        "count": 1,
        "text": "No hay",
        "disambiguation": {
            "subtype": ["NONE"]
        },
        "type": "Quiebre_Stock"
    }, {
        "count": 1,
        "text": "madera",
        "disambiguation": {
            "subtype": ["NONE"]
        },
        "type": "Producto"
    }],
    "language": "es"
}
```

Estoy tratando de mapear el JSON con este metodo

```
parsedJsonObj = mapper.readValue(result, NLUEntitiesRelations.class);
```

y `NLUEntitiesRelations.class` es asi

```
public class NLUEntitiesRelations {
    private UsageNLU usage;
    private List<EntityNLU> entities;
    private String language;

    //getter and setter
}

public class UsageNLU {
    private int text_characters;
    private int features;
    private int text_units;
    //getersand setter
}

public class EntityNLU {
    private int count;
    private String text;
    private DisambiguationNLU disambiguation;
    private String type;
    //getter and setter
}

public class DisambiguationNLU {
    private List<String> subtype;
    //getter and setter
}
```

pero cuando ejecuto esto, obtengo el siguiente error, y cree las nuevas clases para los JSON dentro de los JSON

> Error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token at
>   [Source: { "usage": { "text_units": 1, "text_characters": 22,
>   "features": 1 }, "language": "es", "entities": [ { "type": "Producto",
>   "text": "pisos", "disambiguation": { "subtype": [ "NONE" ] }, "count":
>   1 }, { "type": "Quiebre_Stock", "text": "no hay", "disambiguation": {
>   "subtype": [ "NONE" ] }, "count": 1 }, { "type": "Producto", "text":
>   "madera", "disambiguation": { "subtype": [ "NONE" ] }, "count": 1 } ]
>   } ; line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain:
>   cl.sodimac.watson.alchemy.json.NLUEntitiesRelations["usage"])

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código de la clase `UsageNLU`.

Comment: Esta el codigo de `UsageNLU` justo debajo del `NLUEntitiesRelations`

Comment: Cierto no lo vi.